# Typing "cd.." in Linux terminal instead of "cd .."

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, cd

I come from MS-DOS background, where it is permitted to type `cd..` (without the space between `cd` and `..`) instead of `cd ..`. The Linux terminal, however, finds `cd..` objectionable.

Is there a way to make Linux terminal understand `cd..` to mean `cd ..`?

I'm using Ubuntu.

And I am well aware that this is a rather silly problem, but I have `cd..` committed to muscle memory (since early childhood, my brain has been wired that way) and I've been making that mistake at least twenty times every day, for several years now, ever since I started using Linux on a regular basis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create an alias:

```
alias cd..="cd .."
```

If you add this to some file that's loaded whenever you log in (e.g., `.bashrc` if you're using bash), you'd get the effect of having this alias permanently available.